# How would I condense the following code using "with" statement

Tags: excel, vba

- I am having trouble condensing this code down using "With" statements. Below is my following code. Can someone help me with this situation?

Comment: Why set 4 different number formats?  `With Range("H1:H2")` seems like a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with Range("H1:H2")
    .NumberFormat = ...
    .
    . Here you put everything except Font part 
    .
    with .Font
        .Size = ...
        ...
    end with
end with
```